# Keep-Alive Dropwizard

Tags: java, jetty, dropwizard, embedded-jetty

I understand Jetty can be configured via the config file within Dropwizard, however I cannot find a way to enable Keep-Alive, any suggestions on how to implement this rather than a custom filter?

```
server:
  type: simple
  applicationContextPath: /
  adminContextPath: /admin
  connector:
    type: http
    port: 8080
  gzip:
    bufferSize: 8KiB
```

Answer (score 1):

HTTP keep-alive support is available by default in Jetty when using HTTP/1.0

The use of HTTP/1.0 `keep-alive` is dependent on the HTTP Client (its chosen HTTP version support level, and the headers it sends).

Note that `keep-alive` is an invalid term/concept/setting/header when using HTTP/1.1 (it has no meaning on HTTP/1.1).

HTTP/1.1 is connection persistent by default, and you would need to pass a `Connection: close` header to request that the connection is closed after the current HTTP exchange.

Comment: This doesn't appear to be correct as my headers on a basic Dropwizard app is simply returning my 'connection: close'. Is there any way to enable this explicitly?

Comment: If the request headers have `Connection: close` then its your client.  If the response headers have `Connection: close` then its your application running on dropwizard adding it (jetty will only add `Connection: close` itself in some error cases)

Comment: It's the basic Dropwizard example I am running and attempting to connect using Chrome

Comment: Browsers use keep-alive connections. I am running a standalone default DW app without any config on 1.00 and get keep-alive connections through chrome, while nothing on curl. This is default behaviour

Comment: `keep-alive` is for HTTP/1.0 only. with HTTP/1.1 its a persistent connection by default with `Connection: close` used to exit out of that default behavior.

Comment: is there a keep-alive timeout configuration and default timeout value ?.